# Unreachable objects seem to stay in memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks

I'm trying to fix a memory leak in my NodeJS application. I seem to have fixed the leaks caused by closures and timeouts, but it still seems to be leaking. According to the v8 profiler, many strings seems to stay in memory, but the chain from root simply says:

parent :: "my string content"

All retainers say:

parent in (sliced string) @.......

What am I missing or misunderstanding here? I'm already forcing a garbage collection every time a request is finished, so there should be very few unreachable objects remaining.

This is a screenshot of my heap profiler:

[image: heap screenshot]

Comment: Looks like you are slicing your strings and then still reference its parts somewhere. Show us your code!

Comment: How do you measure the leak, how do you confirm they *never* go away?

Comment: I'm testing the application by running the same operation over and over again. The memory usage for the node process steadily grows from 200 MB to about 2 GB after one hour. After each operation (which lasts 10 or 20 seconds) I call global.gc(), so I assume that any data remaining in memory after that is there to stay. Am I correct?

Comment: I'm afraid showing my code will be rather difficult, because it's a big application and I don't know which part is causing the leak. I don't slice any strings myself, but perhaps some external module is doing it. I do many http requests  using the request module. The strings remaining in memory contain response data from those requests, so either request module or one of the modules I use in processing the data must be doing the slicing. Maybe I can narrow down the problem based on that assumption.

Comment: did you use cheerio for parse html?